# Storing data in the WPF App - looking for solution

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, azure

I'm currently working on WPF App which is calculating things for long string and storing this values in decent variables. By now im storing this values in my local SQL database and showing it by datagrid in WPF window. In the future i want to use this app on others computers, every user would be able to store their values from strings. In this way other users won't be able to use this, because there is my connection string and no database mine database. I need a solution for this. What is the best way to store this items, considering this app would be run on many machines? I need 2 options (FREE users - storing localy in theirs PCs, and Premium (online database, maybe Azure would be ok?)

XLS is only for Excel instaled user, i won't to use this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a embeddable database like SQLite should do the trick

Comment: Reading about this right now and seems it would be good solution. Thank you bro :-)